# How to Mute Animation Nodes Subprogram

Tags: animation-nodes

Just wonder whether subprograms can be totally muted in ways other than just deleting it. I ask bacause:

For example, I tried to setup a loop in another nodetree, Then disable auto execution for that nodetree. However, it can still be invoked in other nodetrees, because subprograms seem to be kinda "global" data.

In some cases I want to mute the subprogram to improve overall performance by disabling the execution. Is that helpful? Can I do that? Or other better solutions? Thanks!

Comment: I think there is no good solution to this yet.. I'm thinking about an additional boolean input in the Invoke Subprogram node that tells the node wether to execute the subprogram or not. Will see.

Comment: Oh I bet that can be helpful especially for complex setups, you know, I mean those with hundreds of nodes, though not sure whether it can make enough sense for a performance leap.

Comment: I thought it might have been possible with the "loop break", but I just tried it out and it does not cause the loop to stop. Which makes me wonder: what is the "loop break" node for and how it is used? but i"ll open another question for that :)

Comment: @KristofMeirlaen There was a [discussion](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/300) on loop break between Jacques and me. FYI

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** **New Version**

Same Principle, but how about ditching additional `Subprogram` and using `Get List Element` instead:

**Old Version**

I put actual `Subprogram`(red) inside another one (blue) as a **Parameter** to get ability to dynamically change number of iterations. Condition is controling execution of blue `Subprogram`

*New:*
[image]

*Old:*
[image]

Comment: 0 iteration, interesting, quite dirty huh. X-D    @JacquesLucke Your opinion here?

Comment: Tried to combine both Subprograms inside one